# nginx relative path to include

Tags: nginx, configuration

In an nginx conf file, is there any way to specify the `include` to another conf file relative to the current conf file?

I would like to write:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;

  include "../apis/basic.conf";

...
}
```

Comment: Nope. All paths are either absolute or relative to prefix path http://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html

Comment: Guessing at your file and folder layout, `include apis/basic.conf;` would probably just work. For example, [this include](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/sites-available/example.com#L36) is relative to the config root, so includes [this file](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/h5bp/basic.conf).

Comment: Changes with nginx 0.6.7                                         15 Aug 2007

      *) Change: now the paths specified in the "include",
         "auth_basic_user_file", "perl_modules", "ssl_certificate",
         "ssl_certificate_key", and "ssl_client_certificate" directives are
         relative to directory of nginx configuration file nginx.conf, but not
         to nginx prefix directory.

Answer (score 6):

The Nginx docs for the `include` directive don't document how relative paths are handled (as of release 1.9.15). My reading of the C code is that the path must be absolute or relative to the prefix path, as Alexey Ten offered in a comment.

Here's a [related link to the source code](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/7cee215f15cf91e40fe5709485e60655292e2c67/src/core/ngx_conf_file.c#L845).

Comment: I just tested on nginx 1.10.3. Setting the `-p` to `.` and tried including `./nginx.conf` from a config file stored in `/tmp`. It errors by telling me that it cannot find `/tmp/./nginx.conf`. Either the `-p` option doesn't do it, or inclusion only includes relative to the config file, or my nginx is broken.

Comment: The `-p` option only affects where `nginx` command looks for the config file. Using `nginx -p . -c ./nginx.conf` will make nginx command look for `./nginx.conf`, otherwise without it, it will lookup the prefix path for the `./nginx.conf`.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to what Alexy Ten commented on above, the default prefix will be used.  But according to this StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25486871/1684819 the -p option can be provided to declare where all relative paths will be referenced to *instead* of the default compiled-in path.

Comment: Works perfectly, good answer